# Scale Animation Causes View to shorten before start of animation

Tags: android, animation, scale

So I have this scaling animation and what it's supposed to do is scale the view to 70% of the full height, and then scale it back to the original size. I have two scale animations with different startOffsets.

The problem I'm having with this is the view scales before the animations even start. So when the animations start, they work with the already-shortened-scaled view.

Here is my animation xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >
    <scale
        android:duration="300"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.7"
        />
    <scale
        android:duration="300"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.7"
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        />
</set>
```

And here is how I call this animation:

```
mScaleTop = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale_top);
mTopView.startAnimation(mScaleTop);
```

Any ideas? Thanks for reading.

Comment: use ONE scale animation with a custom interpolator acting like /\ or like sin() function in the domain 0..pi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

depending on @pskink notice in comments

if your animation had a cycle mode you can only set `android:interpolator` property to `@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"`
so you can use only the **first stage** and then will return to orginal status...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator" >

<scale
    android:duration="300"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:startOffset="200"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.7" />

</set>
```

**Otherwise** if you want to use `linear_interpolator`
you have to scale height from also `1.0` and not from `0.7` because the `1.0` indicate to current status

`android:fromYScale="1.0"` meaning that `100%` of current status and = 70% of orginal status...

so you have to scale height `android:fromYScale="1.0"` to `android:fromXScale="1.42"`

because: `android:fromYScale="1.0"`=70% from orginal size you have to add 42% of 70 to equal 100% of full orginal height....

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

<scale
    android:duration="300"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:startOffset="200"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.7"
    />
<scale
    android:duration="300"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:startOffset="1000"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.42"
    />
</set>
```

Comment: Oooh, this makes so much more sense. Thank you.

Comment: @MohamedZaatari this is not how it should be used,  you should use an Interpolator to make it work,  try CycleInterpolator for example

Comment: @pskink Interpolator used to control acceleration of scaling and not control the positions
you can read [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html) about Interpolator property

Comment: @MohamedZaatari " This allows the basic animation effects (alpha, scale, translate, rotate) to be accelerated, decelerated, **repeated**, etc." OP problem is that case: animation is repeated once and reversed,  just use CycleInterpolator to achive that and not magic stuff like 1/0.7

Comment: @pskink you are right I will update my answer with your useful information...thanks