# Android Scale Animation not smooth

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I don't know how to create a `<scale>` animation on ImageView that works fine, i created one with Vector Drawable that works, but image one is not smooth at all, gif at the bottom:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:width="24px"
android:height="24px"
android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
>

<group android:name="background"
    android:pivotX="12"
    android:pivotY="12">
    <path
        android:name="circle"
        android:fillColor="#F235"
        android:pathData="M12,12m-10,0a10,10 0,1 1,20 0a10,10 0,1 1,-20 0" />
</group>
</vector>
```

Animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="400"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.8"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        />

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="400"
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.8"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        />

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="400"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:valueFrom="0.8"
        android:valueTo="1"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        />
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="400"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:valueFrom="0.8"
        android:valueTo="1"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        />

</set>
```

That's my image scale animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <scale
        android:duration="400"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.8"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.8"
        />

    <scale
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:duration="400"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromXScale="0.8"
        android:fromYScale="0.8"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0" />


</set>
```

Blue one is Vector Drawable, Red one is ImageView animated with `<scale>`

I know it can be solved by deleting second `<scale>` and adding

```
android:repeatMode="reverse"
android:repeatCount="1"
```

to the first one, but i'd like to make it work with two `<scale>`  commands

[image]

Comment: The red circle is visually larger than the blue one. Does it have initially scaleX=1 and scaleY=1?

Comment: You're right, but i think it's because the vector drawable for circle looks like that, i actually don't know how to make it fit ideally like red one, but i don't do anything else with the red circle, so how can the scale not be 1 ?
[Screen here](https://imgur.com/a/6Ct7JC8) and  [circle here](https://imgur.com/a/xeBVDeI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second animation should start with scale `1.0` and end with `1.25`:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:duration="400"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.8"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.8"
    />

    <scale
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:duration="400"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.25"
        android:toXScale="1.25" />
</set>
```

Otherwise, scale `0.8` is applied instantly, without delay of 500ms. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596304/scale-animation-causes-view-to-shorten-before-start-of-animation)

Comment: Oh, so that's how it works, i have to take each `<scale>` as separate animation, thanks a lot.